# How to dynamically add a tag within a div and access it on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My `div` structure should be this:

```
<div id="dashboard">
    <img id="pic1" src="...png" />
    <h6>....</h6>       
</div>
```

To create the `div` I use this:

```
$('<div>', {
    'id': 'dashboard'
}).appendTo('body');
```

I need to append a `h6` tag with text into the above `div`. How can this be done? Also how can I access the text within the `h6` tag when the `div` is clicked?

```
$('#dashboard div').hover(function() {
    alert($(this).children().eq(2)  ??  );
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add the `h6` element, try this:

```
var $div = $('<div>', {
    'id':'dashboard'
}).appendTo('body');

$("<h6></h6>").text("Foo").appendTo($div);
```

To access the text of the `h6` on click of the `div`, try this:

```
$("body").delegate("#dashboard", "click", function() { 
    var text = $("h6", this).text();
    alert(text);
});
```

That assumes you are using jQuery 1.6 or lower. If you are using jQuery 1.7+, you can use `on()`:

```
$("body").on("click", "#dashboard", function() { 
    var text = $("h6", this).text();
    alert(text);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/NaZPM/)

Also, I have used `$("body")` here as an example - you should use a selector which is the closest to the element you are attaching the event to (in this case `#dashboard`) which is not dynamically created.